# BeautifulSoup: identifying scraping approach for webpage object

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape ticket availability dates from megabus' website so I know when to buy tickets. I'm not super experienced with python or BeautifulSoup, but I've been able to work with some example code well enough to collect and parse the main page where the date is listed. When I inspect the page using Firefox I identify 'datepicker-available-span' as the object of interest. However, I'm unable to find the same object when I search the output of the code below.

Any tips on how to collect "Dates available up to Oct 16th" as a changing variable so I can monitor it? Do I need to run a browser like Selenium instead? Thank you for your assistance!

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


# Collect and parse first page
page = requests.get('https://us.megabus.com/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

# Print Page Text
print(page.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The page loads the data dynamically through JavaScript. However we can use `requests` to obtain the available dates. This script will print available dates for route from `Albany, NY` to `New York, NY`:

```
import json
import requests

def find_id(cities, cityname):
    for c in cities['cities']:
        if c['name'] == cityname:
            return c['id']

cities_url = 'https://us.megabus.com/journey-planner/api/origin-cities'
traveldates_url = 'https://us.megabus.com/journey-planner/api/journeys/travel-dates?originCityId={}&destinationCityId={}'

cities = requests.get(cities_url).json()

origin_id = find_id(cities, 'Albany, NY')
destination_id = find_id(cities, 'New York, NY')

traveldates = requests.get(traveldates_url.format(origin_id, destination_id)).json()

print(json.dumps(traveldates, indent=4))
```

Prints:

```
{
    "errors": [],
    "availableDates": [
        "2019-08-17",
        "2019-08-18",
        "2019-08-19",
        "2019-08-20",
        "2019-08-21",
        "2019-08-22",
        "2019-08-23",

    ...and so on.
```

To obtain the last date, you can do:

```
print(max(traveldates['availableDates']))
```

This will print:

```
2019-10-16
```